# Android, button - custom shape

Tags: android, button, charts, pie-chart

I want to create a few buttons in shape of piece of pie chart and i know how to do that, but I have no idea how to place them in one element like a pie chart. 
Any ideas?

I have 5 buttons in this shape:

[image]

and I want to achieve sth like this:

[image]

But I dont know how to do it

Comment: Do they have to be buttons? If so why?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's any way to do this with stock Buttons. What you probably want to do is to extend a `View` into your own custom class, and override the `onDraw` method to draw the pie chart with whatever algorithm you want to use to draw a segmented circle.

Then on `onTouch` you can compare the touch X/Y coordiante versus the pie segments you drew and then do some action based on which segment of the pie was clicked.